# input data not insert to other table using Yii2

Tags: yii2

Does anyone know how to add data to a different table? For example, the Clinicname and ClinicArea information are not saved to the table when I press submit. Data does not display any input information inside the clinic table. The code is given below:

siteController code:

```
 public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    $model2 = new Clinic();

    if ($this->request->isPost) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->signup();

            $model2->save();
          
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for registration. Please check your inbox for verification email.');
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
        'model2' => $model2,
    ]);
}
```

signup code:

```
<div class="site-signup">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<?= $this->render('signupnew', [
    'model' => $model,
    'model2' => $model2,
]) ?>
```

signupnew code:

```
<div class="site-signup">

<p>Please fill out the following fields to signup:</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model2, 'clinicName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($model2, 'clinicArea')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

signupForm code:

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }
    
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();
    $user->generateEmailVerificationToken();

    $clinic = new Clinic();
    $clinic->clinicName =  $this->clinicName;
    $clinic->clinicArea = $this->clinicArea;

    return $user->save() && $this->sendEmail($user) && ($clinic->Id = $user->id) !== null && $clinic->save();
}
```

Comment: Did you add these two columns to  Clinic rules?

Comment: The Problem i think is: you load the Post Data in the $model2 which should be saved. But in the signup function, there is a new Clinic Model created. But here, you have no access to $this->clinicName.